# Is there a way to gpg sign all previous commits?

Tags: git, gnupg

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to gpg sign all my previous commits in a repository (preferably without typing in my passcode for every commit).

Comment: Here's [an old superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits) which has a few answers to this question.

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically using `filter-branch` or something like that? Those solutions require me to go and mess with things in an interactive rebase.

Comment: A commit depends on all previous commits. So if you sign one commit, you are implicitly signing all the history that led up to that commit.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @G.Sliepen here, but I would also add that there are theoretical approaches to breaking SHA-1 that *might*, under some as-yet-improbable scenarios, allow an attacker to replace some intermediate history commit and thereby foil the Merkle hash chain guarantee that signing a later commit implicitly covers all the earlier commits. In other words, GPG-signing *each* commit is in theory more secure today. In practice it's not really worth worrying about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signing an existing commit with GPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737096/signing-an-existing-commit-with-gpg)

Comment: See also answers in superuser discussion [Can you GPG sign old commits?](https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can, but it will have to rewrite your entire history to do so.

Signing a commit changes the commit which changes its commit ID. Since the commit ID depends on the previous commit ID, all commits after that have to be changed. And you're signing them all anyway.

If it's a personal repository that nobody else is working on, then it's not a problem. If it's a repository with other collaborators, treat it like doing a major rebase.

You'd do it with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to redo every commit with the `-S` option.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all
```

As for not having to type in your passcode for every commit, you need to configure `gpg` to use a [gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html). If you're familiar with `ssh-agent` it's a similar idea, it's a little process that you give the password to once and keeps it stored in memory for you. How you do that depends on your operating system and setup. On OS X I let [GPG Tools](https://gpgtools.org/) take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: This worked great, thanks. The answer might be improved by explaining the `filter-branch` command a bit - I'm not familiar with `commit-tree` or `filter-branch` at all so this all looks like magic.

Comment: I get this error when I run the command: `error: gpg failed to sign the data
could not write rewritten commit`.

Comment: This helped me switch from GPG signatures to [SSH signatures](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2021/11/16/git-ssh-signatures/ "Signing Git Commits with SSH Keys"): remove all signatures with `--no-gpg-sign`, and then apply them again as above. Thanks!

Answer (score 77):

My approach is

```
git rebase --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S" -i 8fd7b22
```

All commits started from the next after `8fd7b22` will be rebased with no changes except signing. To change all commits started from the very first one you may use `--root` (since [Git v1.7.12](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.1.txt)):

```
git rebase --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S" -i --root
```

To spread changes to the remote I use

```
git push --force
```

Note, this will update "gpg made" date-time and, for example, GitHub will treat it as commit date. Git itself persists both original and new dates, `git log --show-signature` gives clear picture of when the original commit was made and when it was signed for the last time.

Comment: While this works, I'd like to add that this destroys the actual commit date. @dhilt, you should've considered adding that in the answer as well. So, not "no changes" except signing.

Comment: @roshnet I did little research and updated the answer. If you have anything more, I'd be happy to dig deeper.

Comment: @dhlit No problem, thank you for updating the answer.

Comment: How can I sign the very first commit? I signed all commits after the first, but don't know how to sign the initial commit.

Comment: @sansari Good question! I updated the answer to provide solution (--root).

Comment: @dhilt adding root would pull entire history, not only the current branch

Comment: @sansari use `--root [<branch>]` syntax to specify the branch, reffer to [git-rebase doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: I would like to add that this method destroys the commit tree, and instead commits will be committed consecutively (in graph terminology, it becomes a path). So if you like me would like to preserve your commit-graph, use the accepted answer.

Comment: On Windows shell(e.g. cmder) you may need to change single quotes to double quotes.
`git rebase --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S"` -i 8fd7b22    See https://superuser.com/questions/1656806/why-git-commit-doesnt-recognize-amend-on-git-windows

Comment: Doesn't using `-S` need an identity key passed in? If you use `-s` it will use whatever is stored in your gitconfig.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to filter only specific commits and sign only them you can use `filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "user@domain.com" ];
  then git commit-tree -S "$@";
  else git commit-tree "$@";
  fi' HEAD
```

This is useful if, for some reason, you want to sign only your own commits.

Answer (score 4):

The use-case I wanted to solve is to sign all of my previous commits while keeping the original commits dates.

Sign relevant commits

```
git rebase -i --root
git commit --amend -S --no-edit &&  git rebase --continue # for all the relevant commits
```

Return commit date as author date and force push (don't forget to backup before).

```
git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date -i --root # return 
git push origin main -f
```

Can be automated using the other answers.